# How to show the result of the console in a label Java Script

Tags: javascript, get, display, show

hello i want to show the hello world in a label how can i do it i am new in javascript.Hi guys, I have modified my question to be clearer and to be able to put the example.

```
<script>
```

function word()
{

```
  let call = prompt('please insert a word');
  console.log();
```

}

```
<button onclick="word();">Click for insert a  word</button>
Show my word<input type="text" name="show"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean show it in a label? You may need to expand on your question a bit to better explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi guys what I want to do is to send  the result of what I get in cosola to the label.Can you help me with this simple example?, I do not know how to communicate the console with the id of the label.

Comment: when we click on it we open the prompt and there we enter our word now how do we send it to the show my word label which is called "show".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.group`

I couldn't get a working example using the code snippet but here a quick video:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right, what you'd like to accomplish is taking the text returned from the console.log and displaying it in a html

There's just one way in which you could achieve that.
console.log is just a property of the console object, which is a property of the window object so you can edit it for doing what you want.

```js
const defLog = window.console.log; // saving a reference of the original log, "just in case"

// defining the element in which printing in
const target = document.getElementById("targetId");

// and now i change console.log behaviour for making it printing in the element you'd prefer.


console.log = (s) => {
target.innerText += "> " + s + "\n";
  defLog(s);
}
```

It' wont print just what you type in, but the same exact output it would give you in the console, so like the results of expression or "[object object]" if you pass in an object and so on.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all, may I suggest you to not use a `<label>` element for this. labels are usually used to represents a caption for an item in a user interface, as stated by the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). You should use a `<span>` element for instance.

So first of all you would need to select the `<span>` element from your HTML into the JavaScript. You can achieve that usign the `document.getElementFromID` function for example, but for that we'll first need to give your span element an ID, so your HTML will look like this:

```
    <button onclick="word();">Click to insert a word</button>
    <p>Show my word: <span id="show-word"></span><p>
```

Now in the JavaScript we can select the span element that will be later used to show the word the user gives us:

```
// this will select the element with the id of "show-word" 
// and save it to the variable wordContainer
var wordContainer = document.getElementById("show-word");
```

Then we define the function word like so:

```
function word() {

    var word = prompt('Please insert a word: ');
  
    // we use the innerHTML function to change the HTML of the
    // element stored in the wordContainer variable, our span element
    wordContainer.innerHTML = word

}
```

In case you want to learn more, you can search about DOM manipulation, wich is the interaction of the JavaScript with the HTML, allowing you to change the HTML from your page dinamically from the JavaScript.